# how to change toggle button using void start ()

Tags: java, android

This is my code, I want to run it without button

please help me;

I am interest in android, this is for my final project for school

thanks for attend

**MY Code**

```
package com.andronoise;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    InputListener {

  InputSuara micInput;
  TextView mdBTextView;
  TextView mdBFractionTextView;
  LevelBar mBarLevel;

  double mOffsetdB = 10;
  double mGain = 2500.0 / Math.pow(10.0, 90.0 / 20.0);
  double mRmsSmoothed;
  double mAlpha = 0.9;
  private int mSampleRate;
  private int mAudioSource;

  private volatile boolean mDrawing;
  private volatile int mDrawingCollided;

  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    micInput = new InputSuara(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBarLevel = (LevelBar)findViewById(R.id.bar_level_drawable_view);
    mdBTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dBTextView);
    mdBFractionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dBFractionTextView);

    final ToggleButton onOffButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(
        R.id.on_off_toggle_button);

    ToggleButton.OnClickListener tbListener =
        new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (onOffButton.isChecked()) {
          readPreferences();
          micInput.setSampleRate(mSampleRate);
          micInput.setAudioSource(mAudioSource);
          micInput.start();
        } else {
          micInput.stop();
        }
      }
    };
    onOffButton.setOnClickListener(tbListener);    
      }


  private void readPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("LevelMeter",
        MODE_PRIVATE);
    mSampleRate = preferences.getInt("SampleRate", 8000);
    mAudioSource = preferences.getInt("AudioSource", 
        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
  }

  @Override
  public void processAudioFrame(short[] audioFrame) {
    if (!mDrawing) {
      mDrawing = true;
      double rms = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < audioFrame.length; i++) {
        rms += audioFrame[i]*audioFrame[i];
      }
      rms = Math.sqrt(rms/audioFrame.length);

      mRmsSmoothed = mRmsSmoothed * mAlpha + (1 - mAlpha) * rms;
      final double rmsdB = 20.0 * Math.log10(mGain * mRmsSmoothed);

      mBarLevel.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

          mBarLevel.setLevel((mOffsetdB + rmsdB) / 100);

          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##");
          mdBTextView.setText(df.format(20 + rmsdB));

          int one_decimal = (int) (Math.round(Math.abs(rmsdB * 10))) % 10;
          mdBFractionTextView.setText(Integer.toString(one_decimal));
          mDrawing = false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      mDrawingCollided++;
      Log.v(TAG, "Level bar update collision, i.e. update took longer " +
          "than 20ms. Collision count" + Double.toString(mDrawingCollided));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hahaha same with you.. can you solved my problem codes Ruchir??

Comment: Well...I don't even know what your problem is! What is going wrong? Give me some detail dude!

Comment: i want to run application without press toggle button.. yes it seem no wrong code..

Comment: You can't just say that! I still have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do! EXPLAIN MORE. I really want to help you, but cant with the lack of info.

Comment: my university-level instructor want my application running when the app opened.. without using toggle button or onclick method.. or otherwise when i open my app, the app also running..

Comment: Add your `onClick` logic in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Copy... Paste...!! But how will you decide, when to start and stop the mic?

Comment: Onclick already in Oncreate Methode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do some code whenever the user clicks anywhere.

Okay...I think I may finally understand what you are saying. Every time the user clicks **anywhere**, this method will get called:

```
   @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
}
```

So in your case, the code should be:

```
       @Override
        public void onUserInteraction() {
            super.onUserInteraction();
 if (onOffButton.isChecked()) {
          readPreferences();
          micInput.setSampleRate(mSampleRate);
          micInput.setAudioSource(mAudioSource);
          micInput.start();
        } else {
          micInput.stop();
        }
```

---

EDIT:

From the docs:

[image]

I'm not really sure when you want the code to be executed, but take a look at the diagram, and find the appropriate place. Here's an example:

```
   @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (onOffButton.isChecked()) {
                  readPreferences();
                  micInput.setSampleRate(mSampleRate);
                  micInput.setAudioSource(mAudioSource);
                  micInput.start();
                } else {
                  micInput.stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            Inisialisasi();
            mDisplay.setLevel(0, mThreshold);

            if (!mRunning) {
                mRunning = true;
                start();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            stop();

    }

    private void start() {

            mSensor.start();
            if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    mWakeLock.acquire();
            }

            mHandler.postDelayed(mPollTask, POLL_INTERVAL);
    }
```

Comment: or i will give you my all source code.. still not working Ruchir.. How?? Please..